# How do I merge the 8 GB of "free space" on Macintosh HD under Logical volume group into Macintosh HD?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, core-storage

I did some partitioning using bootcamp 6.0 to install windows that left a 8 GB of free space with cannot be restored normally, How do I get it back? The diskutils cs list shows:

```
Last login: Sat Jul 29 16:51:28 on ttys000
AssASSiNxGAs-MacBook-Air:~ AssASSiNxgA$ diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group F57AE880-8554-4F18-B1FC-6291360C2257
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         120368205824 B (120.4 GB)
    Free Space:   8019730432 B (8.0 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 1A135E2C-54E5-4AA4-9FFA-3444B0E81A47
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     120368205824 B (120.4 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 87ABD6CD-2981-4971-9724-4D7F3CBC95AC
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         None
        |
        +-> Logical Volume FD192884-33A4-43CB-86A6-9CE4E58B3B92
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk1
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          111996153856 B (112.0 GB)
            Revertible:            Yes (no decryption required)
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
AssASSiNxGAs-MacBook-Air:~ AssASSiNxgA$
```

My Disk Utility looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: @klanomath i tried `diskutil cs resize and it said iskutil cs resizeVolume /dev/disk0s2 R
/dev/disk0s2 does not appear to be a valid Core Storage Logical Volume UUID or disk`

Comment: @klanomath what do i use in size option

Comment: @klanomath Thanks! the resize cs worked I used this `diskutil cs resizeVolume lvUUID 0` this resized the lv automatically to maximum/fill-fill,but that was completely random,I didn't actually know what it meant but worked anyway.

Comment: Do you want to post the solution as the answer to benefit the community for the next person who has this problem?

Comment: @Trent klanomoath already did that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resizing a Logical Volume in a larger Logical Volume Group with some free space is done with the undocumented coreStorage-verb *resizeVolume*:

```
diskutil cs resizeVolume lvUUID size
```

with lvUUID: UUID of the Logical Volume (the UUIDs are retrievable by entering `diskutil cs list`) and size (size in b/k/m/g/t | 0 | R)

0 and R are magical sizes and try to maximize the size of the Logical Volume (depends on the system version - doesn't work in all macOS systems).

In your case I recommend:

```
diskutil cs resizeVolume FD192884-33A4-43CB-86A6-9CE4E58B3B92 120128m
```

If you get an error *disk to small* (or similar) choose slightly smaller sizes like 120064m or 120000m until you are successful. The final size of the expanded Logical Volume is slightly smaller than the underlying Physical Volume: some space on the PV is required to store CoreStorage meta data.

Example:

Fusion Drive 3.12 TB:

```
combined PV size:  3120722 MB
LV size:           3106192 MB
∆ (PV-LV) size:      14530 MB (= 14.5 GB or 0.47%!)
```

Comment: yeah you're right in general sense but when it comes to problem like I had using 0 for the resizing job would be better. What do you reckon? (nonetheless it worked for me)

Comment: @Anon IIRC the `0` doesn't work in Sierra...